# How to downgrade and remove rpms in the same command?

Tags: fedora, rpm

I have a problem where in order to satisfy RPM dependencies, I need to remove packages and downgrade them in the same command.

### Imagine the following situation

#### Before

- A v2.0 depends on B,C
- B v2.0 depends on C > 1.0
- C v1.1

#### After

- A v1.0 depends on C
- C v 1.0

If I issue a

```
$ rpm -Uvh --oldpackage Av1.0.rpm Cv1.0.rpm
```

it will fail with "B depends on C > 1.0"

If I issue a

```
$ rpm -e B
```

it will fail with "A requires B" so I appear to be in a catch-22.  The obvious solution is to use a "--nodeps" and remove B before doing the downgrade, but I am creating these commands programmatically so I was hoping to use dependency resolution as a sanity check against an incorrect script.

Is there any way to perform this downgrade without breaking the RPM dependency sanity checks by force?

Answer (score 1):

`yum shell` allows you to specify multiple operations before executing them all within a single transaction.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the --nodeps options to -U before the removal of B if you like.  (or --force is a combination of a few good flags ;-)